# Which route does a cisco router prefer and why?

Tags: cisco, routing, router

I have a small network i packet tracer whith some subnets. I connected the subnets with static routes. In one case I made two routes two the same subnets, but one is a serial connection. I wonder which route will be prefered and why it will be prefered. When using 'tracert'-command I can see that it takes the fastEthernet port. Is there any reason for that?

[image]

Comment: Which route to what destination are you talking about?

Comment: PC0 to PC1. Has the router any preferences concerning the type of the cable (serial or fastEthernet).

Comment: Ah, I now see that your diagram has *two* links between router0 and router 'something', text seems to cover one of the links partially. Please provide a readable diagram and more importantly, provide actual configurations of routers involved and routing tables of those devices.